# How to make a context menu item "selected" in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, handsontable

I'm new to handsontable.js, I am stuck with a small issue. I have created one custom context menu, it works well.

Now when I open a context menu and apply an item and then open it again for the same cell it won't show selected. Does anyone have an idea, how to add such a selection (in a form of small tick mark/right sign/some highlightning)?

Here is my code:

```
$("#tabledata").handsontable({
        data: datas,
        startRows: 1,
        startCols: 2,
        minRows: 1,
        minCols: 2,
        maxRows: 400,
        maxCols: 200,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: false,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        minSpareCols: 1,
        mergeCells: true,
        manualColumnResize: true,
        manualRowResize: true,
        cells: function (row, col, prop) {
            var cellProperties = {};
            cellProperties.renderer = "defaultRenderer"; //uses lookup map
            return cellProperties;
        },
        contextMenu: {

            items: {
                "row_above": {},
                "row_below": {},
                "col_left": {},
                "col_right": {},
                "hsep2": "---------",
                "remove_row": {name:'Remove row(s)'},
                "remove_col": {name:'Remove columns(s)'},
                "hsep3": "---------",
                "alignment" : {},
                "mergeCells" : {},
                "hsep4": "---------",
                "undo": {},
                "redo": {},
                "hsep5": "---------",
                "bold": {"name": "Bold"},
                "italic": {"name": "Italic"},
                "highlighted": {"name": "Highlight"}

            }
        },
        cell: metadata,
        mergeCells: metadata

});
```

Here is the image of how it looks:

[image]

Does anyone have idea? 
All answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but maybe this can help
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.2/demo-context-menu.html
In this example they use

```
      items: {
    "row_above": {
      disabled: function () {
        // if first row, disable this option
        return hot3.getSelected()[0] === 0;
      }
    },
    "row_below": {},
    "hsep1": "---------",
    "remove_row": {
      name: 'Remove this row, ok?',
      disabled: function () {
        // if first row, disable this option
        return hot3.getSelected()[0] === 0
      }
    },
    "hsep2": "---------",
    "about": {name: 'About this menu'}
  }
}
```

the key items to describe the elements of the context menu
and the have access to the selected cell hot.getSelected()
Perhaps you can get the settings of the cell to determine if there is an active property and add the tick